# ajax function doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, return-value

why this javascript function just returns 'undefined' ? I want this to return true or false. 
Here's my code :

```
function Ajax() {
    var XML;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        XML=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        XML=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    XML.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(XML.readyState == 4 && XML.status == 200) {
                if(XML.responseText == '1') {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        return false;
                }
        }

        XML.open("POST","p.php", false);
        XML.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        XML.send("user=f");
}
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: Why downvote this question? In my eyes it is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your

`if(XML.readyState == 4 && XML.status == 200)`

is not satisfying that why its not able to return anything. To verify put other return statement with else to above if condition.

Comment: every return code in XML.onreadystatechange doesn't return value.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your `p.php` is not reachable, so `XML.status` never contains the value 200. Check the reachability of `p.php`.

Comment: the value of XML.responseText is '1' (using an alert function)

Comment: If you can access XML.responseText, where is the problem then? XML.responseText will only be accessible as soon as p.php returns its contents, and this is the case when `XML.status == 200`.

Comment: p.php returns the content but the Ajax function doesn't return it's value

Comment: So then you should write "when calling p.php from the browser, I get '1' as output", or something like that. If you stay unspecific as you have, nobody will be able to solve your question.